# Can two solids, a human and a wooden desk, using only human muscular power to close the distance, actually physically touch at the atomic level?

Tags: solid-state-physics, biophysics

If a human places their hand on a wooden desk, the sense of touch and solidity is actually provided by the repulsion effect of the electron shells of the atoms in the hand and desk giving feedback to the various sensors in the human body.

Can these two things actually physically touch at the atomic level?

In this case we are defining "touch" as the atoms of the hand and desk coming as close to each other as the atoms in the desk are to each other normally.

Using only human muscular power to close the distance, can it be proven that a hand and the wooden desk have physically touched as per the given definition?

Comment: While that question and chosen answer is very informative, it does not address if it can be proven that the two named solids have successfully reached the defined threshold of distance using only muscular power as specified in the working definition of touch given. As such, it is not a duplicate.

Comment: Until *you* give a clear definition of what you mean by "actually physically touch at the atomic level" *and* show that it is different from the criterion in the older question, they are duplicates.

Comment: Distance that the atoms in the desk are normally depends on the type of wood, for example, and does not provide a meaningful measure.

Comment: The desk is composed of oak wood.

Comment: I did give a clear definition.

Comment: @nijineko - no, the definition is not actually clear. So, lets ask this: If I pour water on a piece of wood, does the water 'touch' the wood under your definition?